# Find its radius and location of its Centre

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential

Two fixed charges $-2Q$ and $Q$ are located at the points with coordinates $(-3a,0)$ and $(+3a,0)$
respectively in the x-y plane. Show that all the points in the x-y plane where the electric
potential due to the two charges is 0, lie on a circle. Find its radius and location of its Centre.

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE! This question will likely be closed as the policy of the site of not to answer "do-my-homework" type questions. I would recommend resubmitting your question showing your attempt at a solution and stating clearly what physics concepts you are struggling with.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's understand the problem from very basics. We all know Coulomb's law which states $| F| = \frac {kqq'}{r²} $ now we can see that in the following problem you are required to find the locus of all the neutral points in the x-y plane. So let's start by calculating the force due to the charges at point $ (x,y) $. Before this let's introduce the vector form of coulomb's law  which says $ F̅ = \frac {kqq'}{r³} r̂ $ hint :- you have to write the force expression at a generic point $ (x,y) $ and then equate its magnitude to zero this would generate required locus .

Comment: Please don't answer "do my homework for me" type questions. This isn't a homework help site and answering such questions only encourages more of these types of queries that we don't want.

Comment: @Kyle Kanos  describing an idea and solving a question might not be the same. I didn't even perform any calculation understood!